# Chain of map operations in Spark performance

Tags: java, performance, apache-spark

My Spark job contains a chain of map operations

```
JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = raw
            .javaRDD()
            .mapPartitions(new CustomPartitionMapper())
            .map(new DataSpecialMapper(config))
            .map(new CsvFormatMapper(config))
            .map(new ReportCounters());
```

From the programming point of view code more readable and testable.
The question is about performance.

Will be the chain of mappers interpreted by Spark as one mapper operation and will be performed in the same executor or not? If not what may be the performance impact?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> Will be the chain of mappers interpreted by Spark as one mapper
>   operation and will be performed in the same executor or not?

Spark will optimize multiple narrow transformations into a single *stage*, this means that the multiple `map` tasks will be ran subsequently under the same task umbrella. (See [this blog post for more](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/06/22/understanding-your-spark-application-through-visualization.html))

But, you are still going to be iterating each of these partitions 4 * O(n) times, which is still O(n) but may at a given input size effect performance, which is always something to keep in mind.